# Prevent having more than two same attributes(srcset) when randomly changing attributes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, random, attributes

I made this script for grid gallery that changes images randomly one at the time every 3s, by changing its `srcset` attribute, there's always 15 visible images but array is made out of 28 and since its random sometimes happens that there are 3 or more of the same image, there's chance to have all 15 be the same (crazy small chance but you get my point) and i want to prevent it somehow.

I was thinking about somehow defining that there's always 2 same attributes possible at most, so it wont change other `img` to that attribute if there are 2 of those. Or if its possible, this would be perfect, to have only one of attribute visible and it wont add that to other `img` if there is exactly that attribute.

Im ok with having at most 2 of the same attributes since it will minimize chance of seeing them both at the same time since half is hidden and it will prevent seeig 3 or more.

Heres the jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    //array
    var dice = $('.attachment-lenslight_squares').map(function() {
        return $(this).attr('srcset')
    }).get();

    $('.attachment-lenslight_squares')
        .click(function() {
            var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * dice.length);
            $(this).fadeOut(200, function() {
                $(this).attr('srcset', dice[num]);
            }).fadeIn(200);
        });

    setInterval(function() {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
        $('.attachment-lenslight_squares').eq(rand).click();
    }, 3000);

});
```

Thanks for ideas

Comment: [Unique values in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

Comment: @Satpal thanks but i have no idea how to aply it to my code since my array is generated from classes and its also random, can you somehow help me? Sorry to bother you, im not that good in jq this code took me like 4hours haha, and thanks again